# Query WHERE response is empty enter null

Tags: sql

I need to formulate a query and stuck. Need help with a WHERE x=x but if not enter a null or proceed.

Example.

```
SELECT
    a.value1, a.value2,
    b.vlaue1, b.value2,
    c.value1
FROM
    columnX a,
    columnY b,
    columnZ c
WHERE
    a.value1 = b.value3
    and b.value2 = c.value4
    and c.value1 = a.value5
        or c.value1 is null
```

I need the last WHERE of c.value1 to be either = to its check or if no value enter a null value. Right now it seems to choke and loop.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Do you really have tables named columnX etc,  and columns named value1 etc? Absolutely horrible!

Answer (score 3):

Use join syntax, left join for C:

```
SELECT
    a.value1, a.value2,
    b.vlaue1, b.value2,
    c.value1
FROM columnX a
INNER JOIN columnY b
  on a.value1 = b.value3
LEFT JOIN columnZ c
  on b.value2 = c.value4
  and c.value1 = a.value5
```

Comment: Thank you the LEFT JOIN seems to be the answer. i had tried a JOIN however after seeing response and researching further I see why.